# Where is the MVC4 Scaffolding database located?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding

I have started working with an MVC4 project that has a DefaultConnection enumerated in the web config. (sql server 2005 on a shared dev server)

In an attempt to use MVCScaffoling I've followed tutorials then when I run the `scaffold controller tablename -force` command line I reload the list of sql server database tables do not see the expected

All the existing scaffolding operations work, including the many to many relationship and everything.

However the tables arent' in the databse, so they must be somewhere else.  Where are they? How do I tell MVC scaffolding to do all the work on `DefaultConnection`as opposed to self-determining the location to scaffold at?

Answer (score 1):

If there is any at all, the database file will be located in your `App_Data` folder. You will not see it right away until you click on the show all files icon above your Solution Explorer.

I am not sure what reasons you have on doing scaffolding, but if i were you, i would do `Code First`. That way, you know where everything is and you know you wrote most of it yourself.

Also if this is development, why are you sticking with old server when you could easily be working with 2012?

Comment: Well the '05 server is the one we have a license for on the Dev server. I think the upgrade to the latest license is a cross between expensive and risky and "not broken" (so don't fix)... as for the App_data, sadly no luck. No idea why I can't find the tables from this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh... this blurb: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Says:

> Note: Entity framework will always try to connect to the local SQL Server Express database (.\SQLEXPRESS). Starting with EF 5, Ef will use LocalDb if it doesn’t detect SQL Express running. SQL Express will always get precedence if it is installed, even if you are using Visual Studio 2012.

So it would appear that Scaffolding will not allow me to choose the database where it all happens. Which is a bit of a pain, since I want it to be in the same place as my user tables which do reside in the database specified in DefaultConnection.